# Como conectar no SQL Server com VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Já tentei uns cinco tutoriais.

Veja o código em C#

```
        string minhaString = "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=true;" +
               "Timeout=10;" + 
               "Database =bdcadastro;";

        SqlConnection minhaConexao = new SqlConnection(minhaString);


        try
        {
            minhaConexao.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Versão do servidor: " + myConnection.ServerVersion);
        }
```

O código executa e retorna a versão do servidor.

VB.NET:

```
    Dim minhaString As String = "Server=.\\sqlexpress;" &
        "Trusted_Connection=true;Timeout=10;Database=bdcadastro;"
    Dim minhaConexao = New SqlConnection(minhaString)

    Try
        minhaConexao.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Console.WriteLine("Server version is: " + myConnection.ServerVersion)
    End Try
```

Como estou usando a mesma biblioteca, presumi que funcionaria do mesmo jeito, porém no VB.NET ele me retorna `Instance Failure` e lança uma exceção do tipo `InvalidOperationException` na linha

```
Console.WriteLine("Server version is: " + myConnection.ServerVersion)
```

Por quê?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tira essas 2 barras pra separar o nome da instância.

Muda de `.\\sqlexpress;` pra `.\sqlexpress;` no VB.

Em c# ou você faz "escape" de [certos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available) caracteres ou usa @ antes pra indicar que tudo dentro da string é uma "scape sequence".

```
var instance = ".\\sqlexpress";
```

ou

```
var instance = @".\sqlexpress";
```